# The meaning of the phrases or sentences in bold?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> ***My***, how time flies when you are having fun! Get it? ***Flies? Birds?*** Oh,
>   well. Thank you for spending some time with us. Remember, ***more
>   LearningEnglish Programs are just seconds away.*** And world news follows
>   at thebeginning of the hour. I’m Jim Tedder in Washington. We’ll see
>   you later!

This article is from VOA Special English, the link is:[enter link description here](http://www.chinavoa.com/show-8246-229683-1.html)

Answer (score 1):

*My* here is a very mild oath—an abbreviation of *my God* with the piece which may give offense left out.

*Flies? Birds?*, like the *Get it?* just before, call attention to the very feeble joke the speaker affects to see in the cliché “How time flies ... ”. The story which immediately precedes this closing piece concerns birds and how they fly. The words are cast as questions because the speaker is  is giving you hints and in effect asking “*Now* do you get it?”

*LearningEnglish* is the name of the BBC series of which this program is an episode, and the speaker announces that more programs in the series will follow shortly after—only seconds after—the current program ends. *Away* is used after a distance or time measurement to indicate how distant something is in time or space.

Comment: @ StoneyB  "get it" means "can you get it" , "can you understand it",right?

Comment: @user48070 Yes - specifically, "Do you perceive the joke?"

Comment: I still don't understand "'Flies? Birds?, like the Get it? just before, call attention to the very feeble joke the speaker affects to see in the cliché “How time flies ... ’. "in your answeer

Comment: @user48070 *Time flies ... Do you get the joke? Do you perceive the echo in **flies**? Like **birds** fly? The **birds** I was just talking about? Haha? ... Oh, well.*

Comment: OK, I got what you mean in your answer.